# c++ declaration order (const/type/function)

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, declaration

I was wondering if there is a "fixed order" in which c++ declarations can be made? I'm looking at declarations within a class declaration.

In pascal I would be thinking along the lines of using-const-type-function sequence:

1. **using** objpas; //integer
2. **const** c_limit = 5 ;
3. **type**  t_int_array = array [0..c_limit] of integer ;
4. **function** my_func( a_arg0 : t_int_array ) : integer;

My class declarations are contrary to some users because I use private-protected-public order. But within these sections can the order of declarations be fixed also?

The kind of things I'm thinking of are:

```
type declarations (types, enum, class etc)
friend class
friend functions
static member value
static functions
virtual functions
member function
member value 
operators
bitfields
constructors
destructors
using clause
(..plus any I may have missed?)
```

The background to this is that I'm working on a GUI that allows kids to drag and drop items (e.g. virtual function) into lists (e.g. the virtual-function list) - so its the order of these lists that is important to me.

At the moment there is no fixed order, as per c++. But if a fixed order can be proven to work, then it would help "steer" users into seeing what kind of "lists" are available and drop items into them with min/max viewing.

One area that I'm most unsure about is the order in which functions and member values are declared, because I'm not sure if a member can point to a class function..that kind of thing. I'm stronger in pascal than c++ and would appreciate any thoughts on this please?

Also, I know some users have a preference for the order in which items are displayed, e.g. because they prefer to view the most public items first, but in my case this isn't a factor because the GUI minimizes sections in such a way that I'm able to focus only on the "required order" of the declarations.

Comment: Things have to be declared before they can be referenced. Other than that, there's no fixed order.

Comment: @Barmar inline member function bodies can refer to members not yet declared.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal order in which you can put these kinds of member declarations. Here's a counterexample for types & constants:

```
struct One
{
  static constexpr std::size_t dim = 4;
  typedef float Array[dim];
};

struct Two
{
  typedef float Data;
  static constexpr std::size_t dataSize = sizeof(Data);
};
```

And if you take `decltype` into account, then of course any two such declaration kinds can depend on each other in both ways.

Furthermore, even the private-protected-public order cannot be held fixed. Consider this class:

```
struct Something
{
public:
  typedef std::pair<int, double> Data;

  Data getData() const;

private:
  Data prepareData();
};
```

However, for a drag&drop UI, perhaps you could separate the UI representation and class declaration further. Nothing prevents you from presenting these declaration kinds grouped in the UI, and scattering them according to their implicit dependencies when generating the class definition out of the UI.

Yes, it does require you to parse the declarations (or otherwise understand them) to figure out their dependencies, but it's doable. And there are tools such as [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) available for parsing C++.

It also prevents a few advanced effects which can be achieved with declaration order and inheritance<sup>(1)</sup>, but this shouldn't be a problem in an environment aimed at beginners.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Example of such a trick:

```
struct Base
{
  typedef int Buddy;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Buddy getInt();
  typedef Buddy float;
  Buddy getFloat();
};
```

Comment: In relation to the private-public example struct Something, could the typedef of Data be placed outside the class? That way the section order could be private-public? I guess I'm still thinking in pascal terms where (I think) types aren't declared within classes. Or would this be too limiting in other examples not given here?

Comment: In relation to scattering the items, the class declaration and class definition are placed in different files (*.c++,*.h), the GUI can combine both visually. My preference is for header files to contain specifications and unit files to contain implementation items. Barmar mentioned in prev comment about inline member functions referring to members not yet declared, so this might solve that problem too?

Comment: @MichaelCollier Re: out-of-class `Data`. Technically, it could be declared outside the class. But then it pollutes the namespace, and you cannot have things like `std::vector::iterator` etc. You can of course introduce a fixed order when you impose enough restrictions on which bits of C++ are allowed; but if you do that, why bother with C++ at all?

Comment: @MichaelCollier Re: scatter. Class definition (the part between `{` and `}` in `class X { ... }`) must be present in a header file (or, technically, just present in identical form in all source files referring to that class definition) to be practically usable.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear about the scattering, what I meant was that rather than allowing functions to be defined within the class declaration, they are just declared (and then defined within a c++ file). The gui gives the appearance that the function is defined within the class.

Comment: I see what you mean about std::vector::iterator, it looks like having a restrictive order of private-protected-public is a bad thing so I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a possible solution?

I have taken into consideration the need to declare constants and types in any order, and that they have to be done prior to anything else.

Also, code body cannot be placed inside a function declaration in class.

After that, can the sections outlined below be fixed in the order I have given, or indeed in any other/better order?

```
class t_maybe_this_will_work
{
    //1.
    // This MUST be first, and allow declarations in ANY order
    // constexpr,typedefs,enums,nested classes

    //2.
    // What is best/only order for these..?
    // I have listed them so that functions come before values in case
    // functions are referenced?

    // friend                  classes
    // friend                  functions
    // using                   clauses

    // static                  functions
    // virtual                 functions
    // virtual                 operator
    // non-static,non-virtual  function
    // non-static,non-virtual  operator

    // static                  value
    // non-static              value
    // bitfield                value

    // virtual                 destructors
    // non-virtual             destructors
    //                         constructors

    /*     ***** RULE *****

    The body of functions are NOT defined within the class.

    int not_allowed_body_here (void)
    {
       // defining some code here...
    } ;

    */

} ;
```