# Order of const, type and & in copy constructor parameter

Tags: c++, types, reference, constants, copy-constructor

I was told that the order of the `const`, type and `&` didn't matter as [referenced here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268037/c-declaration-order-const-type-function). My user-defined type is `PNG`.

So I wrote my copy constructor as:

```
PNG(const & PNG);
```

but got the error:

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
    PNG(const & PNG);
```

The solutions on Stackoverflow to an error like this don't deal with a copy constructor so I decided to post a different question.

When I rewrote it as

```
PNG(PNG const &);
```

the error disappeared. What am I missing? Is the copy constructor a special case?

Comment: The [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39268037/c-declaration-order-const-type-function#comment65870703_39268037) to the linked question answers yours, I think!

Comment: `const & PNG` is not a valid declator, the reference qualifier goes last, you meant `const PNG&`. Seems like a good ole' typo.

Comment: You're using the `address of` operator in your first example which doesn't make sense in that context. I think you meant `const PNG&`

Comment: I don't see how the linked question relates to yours at all. The order of specifiers used in a declaration is not discussed in that question. The linked question is about the order of declarations themselves.

Answer (score 2):

This just is an invalid syntax. Remove the qualifier const and you will get

```
PNG( & PNG);
```

that does not make sense. It is the same as to write a pointer instead of the reference

```
PNG( * PNG);
```

In the both cases a type specifier is absent. References and pointers shall refer to a type specifier.

You could write either

```
PNG(const PNG & );
```

or

```
PNG( PNG const & );
```

Pay attention to that opposite to pointers there is no constant reference. For example for pointer you may write

```
PNG( const PNG * const );
```

For reference such a declaration

```
PNG( const PNG & const );
```

is invalid.

According to the C++ grammar references are parts of declarators.  For example you may write

```
PNG( PNG const ( & ) );
```

because declarators may be enclosed in parentheses.